# How to run this code?

Tags: java, html, jsp, forms, http-post

It is simply insertion of data from a HTML form into a database in MySQL using jsp. However I am unable to run this code. May anyone please help me.I want to run this in a way such that the jsp code is called using action attribute of the form tag from the html page of the form.
file name: dbcon.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils"%>
<%@ page import= "java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
 <%@ page import= "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>

<%
String str = "sub";
if(str.equals(request.getParameter("sub"))){
    String choice;

    String user = request.getParameter("txtUser");
    String pass  = request.getParameter("txtPass");
    String addr  = request.getParameter("add");
    //String FOI  = request.getParameter(choice);
    String gend = request.getParameter("optGender"); 
    String lang1 = request.getParameter("lang"); 
    String cntry1 = request.getParameter("cntry");
    File image = new File("fileupload");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Loaded driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Form","root","root");
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("Insert into application values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps1.setString(1, user);
            ps1.setString(2, pass);
            ps1.setString(3, addr);
            ps1.setString(4, FOI);
            ps1.setString(5, gend);
            ps1.setString(6, lang1);
            ps1.setString(7, cntry1);
            ps1.setBinaryStream(8, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
            int s = ps1.executeUpdate();

            if(s>0)
            {
                %>
                <b><font color = Blue>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                <%out.println("Submission Successful!");%>
                </font></b>
                <%
            }
            else{
                out.println("Unsuccessful submission");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   //forname() belongs to Driver class
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

%>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It says page not found.@Ghostranger

Comment: do you have an another jsp which calls this jsp file?

Comment: Nope . Actually it is a form written in HTML whose action is to call this jsp. @Ghostranger

Comment: My suggestion is to go with servlets. Create a servlet and specify it in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Create a servlet insted of jsp for the above code..

After that in web.xml specify the servlet.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>dbcons</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>full_packge_name.dbcon</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then specify dbcons in the html form tag.(dbcons which is specified in the web.xml servlet-name tag)

```
<form method=POST action="dbcons">
</form>
```

this is what you need....

Comment: This would be easy for tracking the code and documentation too.

Comment: Thank you so much...I will try it.